Show difference between two .nc mesh layers
I'm trying to show the difference between two meshlayers. I added the layers from Layer>Add Layer> Add Mesh Layer. The layers are extracted from a .nc-file.
Right now I can see the added layers in my window, both a Maximum file and a file with the Temporal Controller (timeframe of 2 days). Since I analysed some flood risk areas I'm trying to show the difference between different scenarios. How can I see the difference in water depth?


I'm everything but an expert on meshes but to my understanding, you can't directly do that (yet?). My workflow for displaying differences (and I'd be happy if someone has a better suggestion) is to convert the meshes to rasters and subtract the rasters using the raster calculator.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
